# Removing AndroidTest and test from a android source

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a simple andorid studio project, By default it shows package for my project and 2 extra packages for (androidTest) and (test). I want to remove them safely.

Answer (score 4):

You can go in project location and find directory app>src>android test/main. There you can delete your android test module.

Comment: you can remove the testing dependencies . But even if you didn't remove, it'll still work.